# U-SQL script unable to compile after SDK update

Tags: .net, azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

My Data Lake Analytics (U-SQL) scripts stopped compiling after updating the Azure SDK and the Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio (2.2.2).

The Microsoft examples still compile successfully, so there must be something wrong with my project?

Error output:

> Error       Metadata file 'C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\mscorlib.dll' could not be found
>   MyScript.usql.cs    0
>
> Error     Metadata file 'C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll'
>   could not be found     MyScript.usql.cs   0

The path to the facades seems to be strange, but I didn't found out how to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that the error message refers to .Net 4.6. U-SQL should use .Net Framework v4.5 though. Did you switch the runtime version accidentially?

Comment: I can't image how that happened. But indeed the runtime version was set to 4.6. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

The .NET framework version can be set via a drop down at the top of the New Project window when creating a project.  Is it possible that you created a new project with the target framework version set to 4.6?  For the project targeting 4.6 that doesn't work, could you try to change the line following line in the project file v4.6 to v4.5 instead?  You can edit it outside of VS, or in VS you can right click the project, unload it, right click it again to edit it, and finally right click it again to reload it.